# How to get DataGridViewComboBoxCell items and add them to excel data validation list in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridviewcolumn

On the following code i'm exporting DataGridViews to Excel sheets. But some of my columns is DataGridViewComboBoxCell and has specific item list for that cell. I'd like to define them and write them on excel as data validation list.

```
 Public Shared Sub NewMethod(ByVal dgvPa As DataGridView, ByVal dgvHp As DataGridView, ByVal dgvMp As DataGridView, ByVal dgvFe As DataGridView)
        Dim sfd As SaveFileDialog = frmMain.sfdSaveFile
        sfd.Filter = "Excel |*.xlsx"
        sfd.Title = "Save Info Sheet File"
        sfd.ShowDialog()

        If sfd.FileName IsNot "" Then
            Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application
            If xlApp Is Nothing Then
                MessageBox.Show("Excel is not properly installed!")
            Else
                Dim xlBook As Excel.Workbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add()
                xlBook.SaveAs(sfd.FileName)
                xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(sfd.FileName)
                Dim xlSheetPa As Excel.Worksheet = CType(xlBook.ActiveSheet, Excel.Worksheet)
                xlSheetPa.Name = My.Settings.str_infosheet__tabname_pa

                For i = 1 To dgvPa.ColumnCount
                    xlSheetPa.Cells(1, i) = dgvPa.Columns(i - 1).HeaderText
                Next

                For i = 0 To dgvPa.ColumnCount - 1
                    For j = 0 To dgvPa.Rows.Count - 1
                        xlSheetPa.Cells(j + 2, i + 1) = dgvPa.Rows(j).Cells(i).Value

    '       Dim xlRng As Excel.Range = CType(xlSheetPa.Cells(j + 2, i + 1), Excel.Range)
                '       With xlRng.Validation
                '           .Add(Type:=Excel.XlDVType.xlValidateList,
                'AlertStyle:=Excel.XlDVAlertStyle.xlValidAlertStop,
                'Operator:=Excel.XlFormatConditionOperator.xlBetween,
                'Formula1:="<items of combobox will listed>")
                '           .IgnoreBlank = True
                '           .InCellDropdown = True
                '       End With
                '       With xlRng
                '           .Value = dgvPa.Rows(j).Cells(i).Value
                '       End With

                    Next
                Next


                xlBook.Save()
                xlBook.Close()
                xlApp.Quit()

                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlBook)
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp)
                dgvPa.Rows.Clear()
                dgvHp.Rows.Clear()
                dgvMp.Rows.Clear()
                dgvFe.Rows.Clear()


            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

Here i'm trying to add this DataGridViewComboboxCell item list with below code;

```
            '       Dim xlRng As Excel.Range = CType(xlSheetPa.Cells(j + 2, i + 1), Excel.Range)
            '       With xlRng.Validation
            '           .Add(Type:=Excel.XlDVType.xlValidateList,
            'AlertStyle:=Excel.XlDVAlertStyle.xlValidAlertStop,
            'Operator:=Excel.XlFormatConditionOperator.xlBetween,
            'Formula1:="<items of combobox will listed>")
            '           .IgnoreBlank = True
            '           .InCellDropdown = True
            '       End With
            '       With xlRng
            '           .Value = dgvPa.Rows(j).Cells(i).Value
            '       End With
```

But my issue is how can i get the comboboxcell items as an array or another format ? After that how can combine this code in below section.

```
For i = 0 To dgvPa.ColumnCount - 1
                    For j = 0 To dgvPa.Rows.Count - 1
                        xlSheetPa.Cells(j + 2, i + 1) = dgvPa.Rows(j).Cells(i).Value
                    Next
                Next
```

Comment: Could you give an example of what values do you have in the grid cells, and what kind of Formula1 do you want to get by combining them?

Comment: @battlmonstr for comboboxcell values are generally string parameters which is related to my model's options like combobox cell items like {FRM, IRM, None} the one below cell is {Rotational, Fixed} one below cell of this is like {Alpha, Beta, Gamma]

Comment: @battlmonstr in Formula1 i'd like to add this comboboxcell items to that after when i'm open the excel there will be dropdown icon and i can fill from the excel.

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to do with a formula at all, and how that formula might look like? Seems like you have 2 questions in one: how the formula looks like, and how to build it in VB.

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18899730/c-sharp-excel-interop-xldvtype-xlvalidatelist-autocomplete-incelldropdown) seems to have the code you need. Just need to convert from C#

Comment: @battlmonstr my question how to get comboboxcell's items as an array or another method doesnt matter i couldnt get it's items . I would like to check if the cell comboboxcell i'd like to get it's items and write in the formula.

Comment: Just to be clear. Can your read values from the DataGridView as an array? In your code you are assigning them to "xlSheetPa.Cells", but can you just read them and store as an array of strings ?

Comment: @battlmonstr it's writing only datagridviewcell value but i'd like to get items of datagridviewcomboboxcell's items as an array.

Comment: I see. So from a cell you can get to a column by `cell.OwningColumn`, then from a column you have `column.Items` that will give you the combobox alternatives.